# ASP.net Button click issue in chrome

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

Hi
I'm working on an c# ASP.NET app. I have an asp button on my app with an associated server side click event. The button is inside the updatepanel.

Now, this click event is not being fired with Google chrome (works fine on IE, Mozilla).

Please provide a solution for this

Comment: which version of chrome are u using?

Comment: @geek your comment reminded me of this http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2011/05/the-infinite-version.html

Comment: can you tell the code  what you are using in design as

Comment: +1 I've been having this issue as well

Comment: @Oskar:I am using latest version of chrome and it's working fine

Comment: @geek It works for me now as well, but i've been having this issue

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue too, ASP.NET renders the  control differently for WebKit.

I ended up using a normal  on my page, I then created a class that replicated the  with the properties I needed, I could then use this class instead of the  in my code, the advantage for me was I knew then it would render the same across all browsers the same.

You could also use browser a definition file to ensure the control is rendered correctly for Webkit.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use:

```
Page.ClientTarget = "uplevel"
```

On Page_PreInit. This avoids differences on browsers definition and can help you.